# Map Collection inside a Object in POST request in JAX-RS

Tags: java, hibernate, jax-rs

I have a class called Customer.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userId;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String userName;
    private String fullName;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String emailAddress;
    private String password;
    private String country;
    @ElementCollection
    private Collection<ContactNum> contactNums =  new ArrayList<>();
    private String district;
    private String dateOfBirth;
    private String gender;
}
```

and there is a collection of contact numbers.

```
@XmlRootElement
@Embeddable
public class ContactNum {
    private String landLine;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String mobile;

    public String getLandLine() {
        return landLine;
    }

    public void setLandLine(String landLine) {
        this.landLine = landLine;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
}
```

My REST API is getting a POST Request JSON Object which is Customer and Contact number inside it.

```
{
  "userName": "aaaa",
  "fullName": "aaaa",
  "emailAddress": "aaaa",
  "password": "aaaa",
  "country": "aaaa",
  "contactNums" : {
    "landLine": "0000000000",
    "mobile": "0000000000"
  },
  "district": "aaaa",
  "dateOfBirth": "813695400000",
  "gender": "aaaa"
}
```

How can I map that request in my JAX-RS client? My method to get request is this. And I also use Hibernate as an ORM tool.

```
 @POST
 @Path("registerCustomer")
 @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public Response registerCustomer(Customer newCustomer) {
 }
```

Comment: @HarshitShrivastava this is not a Spring application

Comment: Which JAX-RS implementation do you use?

Comment: @TomVW I use Jsersey

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Jackson to handle JSON conversion.

- You can either use a custom deserializer (via [@JsonDeserialize](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/annotation/JsonDeserialize.html)
  on class level).
- Or write an adapter which converts your ContactNum
  to a Collection of ContactNum's.

But if you change your JSON input from

```
"contactNums" : {
"landLine": "0000000000",
"mobile": "0000000000"
}
```

to

```
"contactNums" : [{
"landLine": "0000000000",
"mobile": "0000000000"
}]
```

(contactNums changed from object to array of objects)

This way the conversion should work out of the box.

Comment: _"Jersey uses Jackson to handle JSON conversion."_  Well, it may use, but that's not the default JSON provider.

Comment: I thought com.sun.jersey:jersey-json uses jackson as default provider.

Comment: [Jersey 1.x uses Jackson](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/1.19.1/json.html#json.pojo.approach.section) while [Jersey 2.x uses MOXy](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/media.html#json) as default provider for JSON binding.

Comment: Didn't know that, I removed it from my answer